# Entire Box As Link

Tags: html, css

Essentially, I'm trying to get the entire box to be a link and when you hover over it, the entire box also changes colors. I know this is easily done if I write separate code for each "li" tag but that would be timely. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```css
.genrelist li {
 float: left;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bolder;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 50px;
 background: #fff;
 margin: 15px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-color: #000;
}

.genrelist li:hover {
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background: #000;
 margin: 15px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-color: #000; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
<a href="#"><li><span>Fiction Short Stories</span></li></a>
<a href="#"><li><span>Non-Fiction Short Stories</span></li></a>
<a href="#"><li><span>Comic Strips</span></li></a>
<a href="#"><li><span>Poetry</span></li></a>
<a href="#"><li><span>Biblical</span></li></a>
<a href="#"><li><span>Inspirational</span></li></a>
<a href="#"><li><span>Children's Corner</span></li></a>
<a href="#"><li><span>Comedy</span></li></a>
<a href="#"><li><span>Drama</span></li></a>
<a href="#"><li><span>Chiller</span></li></a>
<a href="#"><li><span>Romance</span></li></a>
<a href="#"><li><span>Science Fiction</span></li></a>
<a href="#"><li><span>Memoirs</span></li></a>
<a href="#"><li><span>In The Feathers</span></li></a>
</ul>
```

They all work when you hover over the word, but only the first item works when you hover over any part of it's box. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Working fine on Google Chrome 41.0.2272.89 m. Can you specify the browser?

Comment: Why have you provided a live example where none of the CSS applies to the HTML provided?

Comment: Move the anchors inside the `<li>` tags and remove the `<span>`. Apply your box styling to your `<a>` tags. You might need to adjust the styling on the `<li>` tags too.

Answer (score 0):

`a` needs to be wrapped into `li` to valid your HTML structure, then displayed as `block`.

A pseudo element can be used to help vertical-align your span.
`display:flex;` could be used too to center `a` content.

Demo using pseudo-element

```css
li {
 float: left;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bolder;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 50px;
 background: #fff;
 margin: 15px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-color: #000;
}

 li:hover {
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background: #000;
 margin: 15px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-color: #000; 
}

li a {
  display:block ;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;}
a:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height:100%;
  }
a span {
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:99%;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><span>Fiction Short Stories</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Non-Fiction Short Stories</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Comic Strips</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Poetry</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Biblical</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Inspirational</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Children's Corner</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Comedy</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Drama</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Chiller</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Romance</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Science Fiction</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Memoirs</span></li></a>
<li><a href="#"><span>In The Feathers</span></a></li>
</ul>
```